# Memory-profile runtime golang program

Tags: go, kubernetes, profiling, memory-profiling

Is there any way to profile a runtime program written in golang?
In my case, kubelet shows steady increase in memory and I want to try memory profiling it.

Comment: If the memory does not plateau, a looking at a stack trace will usually provide more insight than a memory profile. Finding what is allocating memory is very different from finding where you are not releasing memory.

Comment: check out this docs: [node-performance-testing.md#profiling](https://github.com/fabric8io/kansible/blob/master/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/docs/devel/node-performance-testing.md#profiling)

Answer (score 2):

use `import _ "net/http/pprof"` in your application file and use `go tool pprof` commands or web UI to profile your application.

reference -

- [golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/)
- [how-i-investigated-memory-leaks-in-go-using-pprof](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-i-investigated-memory-leaks-in-go-using-pprof-on-a-large-codebase-4bec4325e192/)
- [profiling-go-with-pprof](https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/09/24/profiling-go-with-pprof/)

Comment: Don't blank-import `net/http/pprof` in production, though. At least, don't expose the `pprof` endpoints to the world.